# TS2741 Property '0' is missing in type '{ label: string; } Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, components

Hi I'm writing a code using JS and TS. I've made this interface:

```
> interface IPLTableProps {
>     Conf: [{ key: string, val: any }],
>     Values?: [string],
>     children?: ReactNode // TODO prendere children da React }
```

I defined this interface for create a general component. When I try to use this component in another file, obliviously I have to call is as a general component. But here it comes the error. The general component it's called PLTable

```
 <PLTable Conf={CONF}/>
```

CONF is an array, and when I try to run I get this error.

> TS2741: Property '0' is missing in type '{ label: string; }[]' but
>   required in type '[{ key: string; val: any; }]'.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[type]` defines a tuple with a single element. You probably want an array which is defined using `type[]` or `Array<type>`

```
interface IPLTableProps {
    Conf: Array<{ key: string, val: any }>,
    Values?: string[],
    children?: ReactNode 
}
```